# regex negative lookahead using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

And thanks for your help!

I am trying to do an negative inclusion

I have the following:
0[1-9][0-9]{5}
this works for positive inclusion against this:
**0258714** **0465666** 1213655 568464668 225 75487 021523
56556 **0236589**

but when I try this

(?!0[1-9][0-9]{5})

it doesn't include the opposite
0258714 0465666 **1213655 568464668 225 75487 021523
56556** 0236589

How could we get this to work?

see link for setup:
https://regex101.com/r/OkMliM/1

Comment: You can prepend a word boundary and match the digits `\b(?!0[1-9][0-9]{5})\d+` https://regex101.com/r/8HhsS8/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lookahead by itself is unanchored and will match all the positions where the assertion is true.

What you can do is use a word boundary followed by the assertion. If it is true, then match 1 or more digits.

```
\b(?!0[1-9][0-9]{5}\s)\d+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8HhsS8/1)

added an \s to make it work

Comment: So I tried this with a long string today and it did not take: 
0221547 02556 02662933434343423423423423505 0565 05 any suggestions...
NVM I added a \s in the selector and it works